# How to check if date in associative array and use value associated to this date With SQL Query (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have an associative array as follows:

```
$ a = 
[ 
  "2023-05-18" => 10.0
  "2023-07-14" => 2.0
  "2023-11-01" => 16.0
  "2023-11-11" => 2.0
  "2023-12-25" => 8.0
  "2024-01-01" => 2.0
  "2024-04-01" => 22.0
]
```

And in a SQL query i want to do something like:

```
function ($a) {
     $sql = " ... some code before ...

              IF (table.date IN ($a), value of date (ex 10.0), 1)
            "
          ;
}
```

Not only with if with case when, or whatever the idea is to get the value in associative array according to the date (if it exist in the array);

Comment: Hint: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php . But beware of SQL injection if the data isn't hard-coded. You can use a related approach to generate a list of parameter placeholders instead though.

Comment: @ADyson This is not really my problem i know that sql can't parse an array, i only cant figure it out how to get the value according to the key for the moment and i'm stack at this point. thanks for the hint anyway

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then. Show exactly what you want the sql query to look like at the end

Comment: @ADyson I don't really know how it will look like, i mean here is what i want in pseudo code: iF '2023-05-18' IN my_array Use 10 else use 1

Comment: If you don't know how it should look, how do you expect to be able to write code to achieve it? Is your real question actually about how to write the sql query? Try writing that hard-coded, and then worry about how you'd build it dynamically using php

Comment: @ADyson I think the question is clear enough, and i dont need to write anything in PHP, please take time to understand it, otherwise this kind of comments are not helping at all. Thanks anyway

Comment: You say you don't know what SQL query you want to write, but nevertheless you want us to write PHP to generate that query. And you think that's a clear requirement? Ok then, it's your call but I disagree - from experience, programming to a poorly-defined or undefined specification is very difficult. We'll see how many answers arrive. Like I said, it sounds like your first question should actually be a SQL one, about how to get the right type of query (regardless of whether it has data hard-coded or added in via PHP).

Comment: It would also help a great deal if you'd show some sample table data, and the expected output you want from the query. Right now we only have some vague psuedo-code out of context. We don't even know if the query should be a SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE or whatever, or where this `IF` idea fits into it. There's too little context. Please see [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue, for more guidance. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) is also useful.

Comment: @ADyson you said "but nevertheless you want us to write PHP to generate that query" I don't want you to generate any PHP code. the question is simple i have an array with keys and values and inside my query at a certain point i want to make an if condition or case when statement to say IF the date is presented in my array (as key) use the associated Value. thats all

Comment: Well if you want to use that array, which is a PHP array, then that clearly involves writing PHP code doesn't it? And it seems like you want to use that PHP to make something in SQL, but it's not exactly clear what this is. You said `IF the date is presented in my array (as key) use the associated Value`...what date exactly? And "use" the value for what? Where is that date coming from? If it comes from a table in your database then we somehow have to write some PHP to generate some SQL to select the date and compare it to each array item. Also is it one date, or lots of rows of dates, or what?

Comment: @ADyson In My Question this was written. IF (table.date IN ($a), value of date (ex 10.0), 1) which means date comes from table. And this was the array i showed in my question $ a = 
[ 
  "2023-05-18" => 10.0
  "2023-07-14" => 2.0
  "2023-11-01" => 16.0
  "2023-11-11" => 2.0
  "2023-12-25" => 8.0
  "2024-01-01" => 2.0
  "2024-04-01" => 22.0
]

Comment: Ok that doesn't answer the question about how many rows there are in the database - it is just one date in there, or many? And you also still didn't answer what you want to actually do with these values once you match them with a database item? I don't think these are complicated questions. We are not mind-readers, it's unclear what the purpose is or what exact output you want. Maybe the answer below helps you though, I don't know?

Comment: Is the requirement really "list all the values from the PHP array where the date key matches at least one row from the SQL table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to do that is to concatenate the logic with your query   and use a case when to handle that. something like

```
$s= "*\nCASE\n";

foreach ($yourArray as $dateKey => $dateValue) {
    $s .= "WHEN DATE_FORMAT(table.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '" . $dateKey . "' THEN 
          " . $dateValue . " \n"
    ;
}

$s .= "END\n";
```

And in you query you can directly do something like

```
    "query do something
         ". $s ."
      do something again "
```

I hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you want is not very clear, but from the conversation and a bit of assumption I think it probably boils down to:

"list all the values from the PHP array where the date key matches at least one row from the SQL table"

If so, then here's one way you could do it:

- Run a query which returns a distinct list of dates from the table where the date matches one of the keys in the array. This effectively gives you a list of dates which appear in both the array and the database.
- Loop through that list to show the values matching those array keys.

Now here's some sample code. There may be a more efficient way to do it, but this is my initial thought:

```
$a = 
[ 
  "2023-05-18" => 10.0,
  "2023-07-14" => 2.0,
  "2023-11-01" => 16.0,
  "2023-11-11" => 2.0,
  "2023-12-25" => 8.0,
  "2024-01-01" => 2.0,
  "2024-04-01" => 22.0
];

$dates = array_keys($a);
$params = array_fill(0, count($dates), "?");

//sql to get all rows from database which match dates in the array
$sql = "SELECT `date` from `table` WHERE `date` IN (".implode(",", $params).")";
echo $sql; //just for debugging

//let's assume you're using PDO and have a connection object named $pdo, for the sake of argument
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $pdo->execute($dates);
$data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//loop the returned set of matching dates
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    //output values from the original array which match the dates returned from the database
    echo $a[$row["date"]].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Related documentation:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php